# How can I access spotlight search on Macos from custom program?

Tags: macos, spotlight

can I somehow access spotlight search results from custom program?

User can install app to any location.

I want to find such installed app's path. I can find through "/", but that rather takes some time. On the other hand spotlite search seems to find the app very fast.

Can I somehow take advantage of that to find custom install location of my app? (For the purpose of installer)

Comment: Ideally if you can recommend how to use it from VMware install builder.

Answer (score 0):

As usually, after posting a question, I found the answer.

`mdfind` is a cli tool to look for.